# KML overlays with tiled images in incorrect positions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have made a map with a series of overlays of old maps that I created using MapTiler and the coordinates were definitely correct when I plotted them in Google Earth, but when I load the KML files in Google Maps they are roughly in the correct area but are far from accurate.

As the same error is replicated in all the layers can someone suggest what it is that I am doing wrong?

http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/withtiledoverlays/19x/doc.kml
http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/kmzdata/withtiledoverlays/20x/doc.kml

The other KML files can be found by changing the URL to 21x, 22, 23x, 25x, 26x, 27x (I am unable to post more than two links).

Comment: [Looks like it might be a different projection](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Fwww.southdevonaonb.org.uk%2Fcordialemapping%2Fkmzdata%2Fwithtiledoverlays%2F19x%2Fdoc.kml&aq=&sll=23.691294,34.706462&sspn=53.955675,78.046875&vpsrc=0&t=h&ie=UTF8&z=13).  [Google Earth projection](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148110&topic=2376768&ctx=topic)

Comment: Thanks! That appears to be the reason... I presumed (wrongly) that they used the same projection. I found this question helpful in finding more info: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/why-are-the-tile-coordinates-different-in-google-maps-and-google-earth