# google maps image overlay bounds doesn't match google earth?

Tags: google-maps, overlay, google-earth

I am trying to put an image overlay on google map with bounds. But the image is not mapping to the bounds. I tested using the same bounds in google earth and it works fine there. Can someone please let me know if I need to anything different with google maps to use the same bounds??

Comment: possible duplicate of [KML overlays with tiled images in incorrect positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486641/kml-overlays-with-tiled-images-in-incorrect-positions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using GroundOverlay instead of OverlayView